# Sympy - inverse conversion rules

Tags: sympy

**PURPOSE:** As part of a project, I would like to implement an automatic converter. My goal is to be able to determine the equation to convert my `y` to `x`. Let's take a simple example: If I convert my `x` values with the equation

```
        y = log10((100 - x)/x),
```

I would be able to identify the equation to convert `y` to `x`, i.e.,

```
        x = 100/(1 + 10**y).
```

**ISSUE:** I'm a beginner on sympy, but I'm convinced that this tool can help me do this kind of manipulation.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I'm not asking the community to give me a ready-made solution, but only the people familiar with sympy to give me suggestions on the most appropriate tools to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're just looking for `sympy.solve`.

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> import sympy
>>> eq = sympy.Eq(y, sympy.log((100-x)/x, 10))
>>> sympy.solve(eq, x)
[100/(exp(y*log(10)) + 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well. I would like to understand if this function can be used for this purpose and any equation type?

Comment: Like [the docs say](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations), if the equation is algebraic AND it doesn't fool SymPy somehow, `solve` is the way to go.